# Error when trying to convert base64 string to image in Python

Tags: python, image, encoding, web-applications, decoding

I am trying create a Python dashboard in which a user uploads an image and then the image is analyzed. The uploaded image is received as a base64 string and it needs to be converted to an image. I have tried

```
decoded = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_string))
image = Image.open(decoded)
```

but I received this error:

cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000268954E9888>

Comment: Could you convert a know image into Base64, and convert it back. Do you get the same image? I suspect that your "base64" (which it is also an error) is wrong. About `base64`: is the name attached to a module name or your local variable? [Important: also on examples: try to get better variable names. Get good habits, from beginning!].

Answer (score 0):

`Image` needs a file-like object, the sort of thing returned by an `open`.  The easiest way to do this is using a `with` statement:

```py
decoded = base64.b64decode(base64)
with BytesIO(decoded) as fh:
    image = Image.open(fh)
    # do stuff with image here: when the with block ends
    # it's very likely the image will no longer be usable
```

See if that works better for you.  :)

Comment: You are using twice `BytesIO`. Is it intentional? Could you explain why it should works? [but for duplicate BytesIO, the core is exactly the same as OP. Just that with close automatically the *file*]

Comment: Sure: scrivener's error, guv!  Will fix.  Thanks for the spot!